# Insert i th vector number into data frame column name - R

Tags: r, loops

This is likely a quick fix! I am trying to place the ith position of my vector into my data frame column name. I am trying to use paste0 to enter the ith number.

```
sma <- 2:20
> sma
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

# Place i number from sma vector to data frame column name
spx.sma <- df$close.sma.paste0("n", sma[i])
```

Column name should read:

```
"close.sma.n2"
```

If I print

```
paste0("n", sma[i])
```

I obtain:

```
> paste0("n", sma[i])
[1] "n2"
```

So really if i paste this into my data frame column name then it should read:

```
close.sma.n2
```

What is the correct method to achieve this?

I achieve the error:

```
> spx.sma <- df$close.sma.paste0(".n", sma[i])
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: You need to use this format, rather than the `$` version... `df[,paste0("close.sma.n", sma[i])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat the dataframe as a list.  So avoid the "$" operator and instead use [[]].

so:

```
spx.sma <- df[[paste0("close.sma.n", sma[i])]]
```